# CALayers never calls it's delegate's drawLayer:inContext: even after [layer setNeedsDisplay] and [layer display]

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, core-graphics, calayer

I can't figure out why the CALayer's I'm creating are not calling their drawLayer method. I've created a drawLayer delegate object for them, yet it never gets called. From a UIView subclass:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

       UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
       // I have a property called 'bg' to reference the child UIView
       self.bg = bg;
       [self addSubview:self.bg];

       // an NSObject subclass I use as a CALayer delegate
       MyLayerDelegate *drawer = [MyLayerDelegate new];
       self.drawer = drawer;


       CAGradientLayer *layer = [CAGradientLayer layer];;
       layer.delegate = self.drawer;
       layer.name = @"bg";

       [self.bg.layer addSublayer:layer];

       [layer setNeedsDisplay];
       [layer display];

    }
    return self;
}
```

In self.drawer I have:

```
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    NSLog(@"layer called drawLayer");
    // Some drawing goes here
}
```

I've tried many different things. I've tried setting setNeedsDisplay on self.bg.layer, I've tried setNeedsDisplay on self.bg, I've tried [layer setNeedsDisplay] before AND after addSublayer, I've tried [layer display] before and after addSublayer. I've tried with and without [layer display] and [layer displayIfNeeded].

Why does the layer refuse to draw?

Answer (score 10):

The layer frame needs to be non-zero. This solved the problem:

```
layer.frame = self.bg.bounds;
[layer setNeedsDisplay];
[self.bg.layer addSublayer:layer];
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you have this method implemented in your Layer's delegate ? If YES this method of your layer delegate will be called.

```
- (void)displayLayer:(CALayer *)layer
```

If you read the Apple's documentation for setNeedsDisplay it clearly says that

```
Calling this results in the layer potentially calling either the displayLayer: or drawLayer:inContext: method of its delegate.
```

You should not implement displayLayer if you do not want to set Layer's content directly and rather want to draw the contents of your layer. You can then do the drawing in drawLayer:inContext: method which should get called instead.

Comment: I didn't know about that method. I put it in my delegate, and it indeed gets called. drawLayer still isn't being called though. Am I supposed to manually call it from displayLayer?

Comment: Having no displayLayer method defined did not solve the problem. But I figured it out. See my answer above.